# Redirect or copy Lambda out to S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a NodeJS script that works fine and outputs to Lambda console. How do I direct the Lambda console output to a S3 bucket.

Below is the NodeJS code:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log("Start")
    let res = await sign(header, payload, keyId)
    console.log(`JWT token:\n [${res}]`)
}
```

Comment: It goes to CloudWatch Logs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html Why do you want it to also go to S3?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using AWS Lambda extensions as detailed here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-lambda-extensions-to-send-logs-to-custom-destinations/